# UIViewController in storyboard reference class from other target

Tags: ios, xcode

I have project with 2 targets: CoreD and MultiT.
Each target contains: Main.storyboard and ViewController.swift
Each of these files has target membership only in its own target.

[image]

When i open Main storyboard in CoreD target, to create outlets and actions, ViewController class in identity inspector is class from other target(MultiT), not from target to which storyboard belongs.

[image]

My XCode version is 9.4.1

Is there way to fix this, other than changing names of view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the vc from

> Manual ->TargetName->ViewController.swift

Then hook the outlets & actions , you'll be able to connect them if the vc is inside the target of the storyboard and assigned correctly as the class name despite it's not showing as automatic as xcode sometimes glitches in it

Comment: After connecting outlets and actions on appropriate controller, it start working. Thanks.